# Isomorphism classes of quadratic forms associated to a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a paper which states something about having an isomorphism class of quadratic forms associated to a bilinear form. From my understanding, the quadratic form $q$ associated to a bilinear form $B$ is given by $x \mapsto B(x,x)$.

Thus there exists one quadratic form that we associated. What is meant here by isomorphism classes of associated quadratic forms to the bilinear form $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it is difficult to answer the question but sometimes one considers two bilinear forms $B,B'$ equivalent (or isomorphic) if there exists an invertible map $A \colon V \rightarrow V$ such that $B(x,y) = B'(Ax,Ay)$ for all $x,y \in V$. If we consider the associated quadratic forms $q,q'$ we see that $q'(Ax) = q(x)$ so we can say that $q,q'$ are equivalent (or isomorphic) if there exists an invertible linear change of variables $A$ such that $q(x) = q'(Ax)$ for all $x \in V$.

For example, if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ then equivalence classes of symmetric bilinear forms (or equivalently, quadratic forms) are parametrized by the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms).